How to Highlight the face when selecting all its vertices?
So, the issue is that I switched blender theme to "Maya" and, as a result, now when I select all the vertexes of the face, the face itself isn't highlighted in viewport. But I actually want this to be highlighted. Is there a way to fix this?

In Header > Edit > Preferences > Theme > 3D View, you'll find 2 colors for indicating face selection:


Face Selection, for the incidental selection of a face outside Face Mode. (In the 'Maya' theme, the Alpha of that color is set to 0)
Face Mode Selection for the explicit selection of a face in Face Mode

You could eyedrop-copy the 'Face Mode' color to the 'Face' color, or set it to your preference.

Thank you! You're a real life saver :D
